# openMCT: getting error while trying to install modules

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to install and run [Open Mct](https://nasa.github.io/openmct/).

In the [getting started page](https://nasa.github.io/openmct/getting-started/) they ask to: 
1. clone the repository "git clone https://github.com/nasa/openmct.git"
2. npm install
3. npm start

When i'm trying to "npm install" i get some errors.
i tried it in 2 different computers and both ended up having the same following error:

```
PS C:\code\openmct> npm install

> openmct@1.0.0-snapshot prepare C:\code\openmct
> npm run build:prod


> openmct@1.0.0-snapshot build:prod C:\code\openmct
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack

Hash: 77a6c86a519d4235aa9f
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 14777ms
Built at: 02/10/2020 4:09:54 PM
 11 assets
Entrypoint openmct = openmct.js openmct.js.map
Entrypoint espressoTheme = espressoTheme.js espressoTheme.js.map
Entrypoint snowTheme = snowTheme.js snowTheme.js.map
Entrypoint maelstromTheme = maelstromTheme.js maelstromTheme.js.map

ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/espresso-theme.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: import file cannot be resolved: "@import "~styles/vendor/normalize-min";" @C:\code\openmct\src\plugins\themes\espresso-theme.scss
    at Object.importReplacer (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:206:19)
    at importReplacer.throw (<anonymous>)
    at onRejected (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\co\index.js:81:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:311:5
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)

ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/maelstrom-theme.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: import file cannot be resolved: "@import "~styles/vendor/normalize-min";" @C:\code\openmct\src\plugins\themes\maelstrom-theme.scss
    at Object.importReplacer (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:206:19)
    at importReplacer.throw (<anonymous>)
    at onRejected (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\co\index.js:81:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:311:5
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)

ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: import file cannot be resolved: "@import "~styles/vendor/normalize-min";" @C:\code\openmct\src\plugins\themes\snow-theme.scss
    at Object.importReplacer (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:206:19)
    at importReplacer.throw (<anonymous>)
    at onRejected (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\co\index.js:81:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:311:5
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js!src/plugins/themes/espresso-theme.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *

    ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/espresso-theme.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib!./src/plugins/themes/espresso-theme.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: import file cannot be resolved: "@import "~styles/vendor/normalize-min";" @C:\code\openmct\src\plugins\themes\espresso-theme.scss
        at Object.importReplacer (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:206:19)
        at importReplacer.throw (<anonymous>)
        at onRejected (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\co\index.js:81:24)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js!src/plugins/themes/maelstrom-theme.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *

    ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/maelstrom-theme.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib!./src/plugins/themes/maelstrom-theme.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: import file cannot be resolved: "@import "~styles/vendor/normalize-min";" @C:\code\openmct\src\plugins\themes\maelstrom-theme.scss
        at Object.importReplacer (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:206:19)
        at importReplacer.throw (<anonymous>)
        at onRejected (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\co\index.js:81:24)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js!src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *

    ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib!./src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss)

    ERROR in ./src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib!./src/plugins/themes/snow-theme.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/fast-sass-loader/lib/index.js):
    Error: import file cannot be resolved: "@import "~styles/vendor/normalize-min";" @C:\code\openmct\src\plugins\themes\snow-theme.scss
        at Object.importReplacer (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\fast-sass-loader\lib\index.js:206:19)
        at importReplacer.throw (<anonymous>)
        at onRejected (C:\code\openmct\node_modules\co\index.js:81:24)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! openmct@1.0.0-snapshot build:prod: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the openmct@1.0.0-snapshot build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-10T14_09_54_865Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! openmct@1.0.0-snapshot prepare: `npm run build:prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the openmct@1.0.0-snapshot prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-10T14_09_54_905Z-debug.log
```

Anybody knows what is the problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a windows related problem, see [this issue](https://github.com/nasa/openmct/issues/2604).

In the folder "openmct\src\plugins\themes" I replaced the paths from the *.scss files starting with "~stytles" with "../../styles" and installation finished sucessful.